# How to calculate confidence intervals for circular data?

Tags: confidence-interval, circular-statistics

I managed to convert my data i circular/polar data (angle, r). Now I would like to compare two treatments to see if they are statistically different. I thought to use the Watson's U2 test but apparently it is only valid when the sample size is bigger than 17 (mine is n=12 per treatment). I read somewhere that we could compare the confidence interval of the mean angle defined for each treatment. Does someone know how to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Watson test is valid for smaller sample sizes too; it's just the asymptotic distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis doesn't work well when $n \leq 17$.  The test has exact values calculated via permutation for smaller sample sizes, although the software you are using may not provide those.

Comment: I am not sure to understand how I could solve my problem. I also have a lot ties in my samples (similar values) so i think it is another reason not to use the watson test. What software do you reckon to use?